# Second Broadcast Receiver is called immediately as of one?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Problem:- I have two broadcast receiver classes. One is called at midnight and it fetches the scheduled alarm time and the second broadcast receiver is called when current time is matched with the store alarm time. But instead of this, AS THE first broadcast receiver is called, the second is also called after finishing the first broadcast receiver function.

Function to call first broadcast receiver:

```
private void setTheTimeToUpdateTables(Context context) {

    Log.i("Update table function","Yes");

    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(context,UpdateTables.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    alarmStartTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    System.out.println("Updating table time "+alarmStartTime);
    System.out.println("Time in millseconds "+alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis());


    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

    Log.d("Alarm","Set for midnight");


}
```

//First broadcast receiver class

```
public class UpdateTables extends BroadcastReceiver {

    DbHelper dbHelper;
    ArrayList<ListMedicine> reminderInfo;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        dbHelper=new DbHelper(context);
        reminderInfo=dbHelper.fetchDataFromReminderinfo();

        for (int i=0;i<reminderInfo.size();i++)
        {
            ListMedicine listMedicine=reminderInfo.get(i);

            Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

            System.out.println("Alarm Hour "+listMedicine.getReminder_hour());
            System.out.println("Alarm Minutes "+listMedicine.getReminder_min());

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,listMedicine.getReminder_hour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, listMedicine.getReminder_min());

            setAlarm(calendar,context,i);

        }


        Log.i("Service Start", CalculateDaysService.TAG);

        context.startService(new Intent(context,CalculateDaysService.class));

        //Call all the alarm here only.. for next day alarm, call from here.



        Log.i("Done","Yes");
    }


    private void setAlarm(Calendar calNow, Context context, int request_code) {

        Log.i("Inside setAlarm,","Yes");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        Long time=calNow.getTimeInMillis();

        System.out.println("Reminder Time is "+calNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+" "+calNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        Log.i("Target",time.toString());

        //final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, request_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

//Second Broadcast Receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context k1, Intent k2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("Alarm Received","Yes");

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

        System.out.println("Alarm Receiver call is "+ calendar.getTime() );
        Intent i=new Intent(k1,AlertDialogActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        k1.startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

Manifest :-

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":remote"/>

<receiver android:name=".UpdateTables"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you wanna to launch your receiver at `alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis()` time

```
     Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

  alarmStartTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

  alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
  alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);
  alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

   System.out.println("Updating table time "+alarmStartTime);
   System.out.println("Time in millseconds "+alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis());
```

and you think

You store and retrieve this value by:

`Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();`

BUT THIS IS WRONG

To store the value use this:

```
SharedPreferences prf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Editor editor = prf.edit();
editor.putLong("SOMESTRINGVALUETOSAVE",alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis());
editor.commit();
```

to obtain:

```
 SharedPreferences prf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
long default_val = System.currentTimeInMillis();// I do not know your default value.
long your_millis = prf.getLong("SOMESTRINGVALUETOSAVE", default_value);
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong.. My first broadcast receiver is launching at the right time.. In the update tables receiver class, I am fetching stored alarm time from sqlite database using reminderInfo=dbHelper.fetchDataFromReminderinfo(); .. So again I want to launch second broadcast reciever at the fetched time alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);

Comment: So, change `time` variable to a proper value in the future

Comment: did.. time value will fetch from db using.. reminderInfo=dbHelper.fetchDataFromReminderinfo();

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal , check is this value really in future